# Is there ROS documentation in languages other than English?

Tags: ros, world

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do other people around the world use ROS? Or is it only a US thing?

Is there ROS documentation in languages other than English?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9077/is-there-ros-documentation-in-languages-other-than-english?/) by [Alex Bravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27/alex-bravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 901 on 2011-02-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There has been some preliminary work to translate some ROS documentation into Japanese and Korean. See: [mailing list thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.science.robotics.ros.user/11025).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0